# How can I substitute one dictionary's missing contents with content from another dictionary?

Tags: dictionary, lua

So, I'm doing translations for a game, and I have different dictionaries. If a translation doesn't exist in one language, I want to set it to the English translation. Every method I've tried to combine the dictionaries has ended up incredibly inefficient.

Here are some cut down examples

```
local translation-sr = {
    Buttons = {
        Confirm = "Потврди";
        Submit = "Унеси";
    };
    Countries = {
        Bloxell = "Блоксел";
        USA = "Сједињене Америчке Државе";
    };
    Firearms = {
        Manufacturers = {
            GenMot = "Џенерални Мотори";
            Intratec = "Интратек";
            TF = "ТФ Оружје";
        };
    };
};

local translation-en = {
    Buttons = {
        Confirm = "Confirm";
        Purchase = "Purchase";
        Submit = "Submit";
    };
    Countries = {
        Bloxell = "Bloxell";
        USA = "United States";
    };
    Firearms = {
        Manufacturers = {
            GenMot = "General Motors";
            Intratec = "Intratec ";
            TF = "TF Armaments";
        };
    };
    Languages = {
        Belarusian = "Belarusian";
        English = "English";
        French = "French";
        German = "German";
        Italian = "Italian";
        Russian = "Russian";
        Serbian = "Serbian";
        Spanish = "Spanish";
    };
};
```

Comment: "*Every method I've tried to combine the dictionaries has ended up incredibly inefficient.*" How "efficient" does it need to be? It is a scripting language after all.

Comment: I mean it's not versatile at all, I don't want to constantly update the code if I add a new layer.

Comment: OK, but where's the layering code? You've only shown us a bunch of tables; how do you use them? How do you substitute values in the default table for values absent in the non-default one?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to figure out, my past methods have been super silly.

Comment: How can someone answer your question if you don't explain what you would consider "super silly" or "inefficient" and what you would consider acceptable?

Comment: I'm just saying my past methods have been bad, and I'm seeing if there's an easier way of doing this. What I was doing is nesting four for loops to check for all possible layers, but like I said, that's silly and inefficient, and if a translator adds another layer the script has to be updated.

Comment: This code does not compile. Try `translation_sr` instead of `translation-sr`.

Comment: That is why nesting is not practical (also it's slower), you should use longer indexes and a flat table instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to do something like this

```
setmetatable(translation_sr.Buttons,{__index=translation_en.Buttons})
```

for all leaf subtables. You can do this by hand if there are only a few subtables.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you should use a metatable to accomplish what you need.

I assume that you will always index by the English default word. With that true you can do the following.

```
local function default(t,k)
    return k
end

local translation_sr = {
    Button = setmetatable({
        Confirm = "Потврди",
        Submit = "Унеси",
    },
    { __index = default }),

    Countries = setmetatable({
        ["Bloxell"] = "Блоксел",
        ["United States"]= "Сједињене Америчке Државе",
    }, 
    { __index = default }),

    Firearms = {
        Manufacturers = setmetatable({
            ["General Motors"] = "Џенерални Мотори",
            ["Intratec"] = "Интратек",
            ["TF Armaments"] = "ТФ Оружје",
        }, 
        { __index = default }),
    },
}
```

This function simply returns your key that was not present in the table.

```
local function default(t,k)
    return k
end
```

With this key being assumed to be the English word you would use as the default the returned value for `"Purchase"` you would get `"Purchase"` back from the `translation_sr`. This method requires no `translation_en` table